# Range.Paste - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a very simple procedure that copies a range from one workbook and pastes it into another; the issue is, I'm getting the error in the title on the `paste` line.

Below is the code:

```
Sub copypasta()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = ActiveWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("F:\Target\FTB\FTB.xlsx")

x.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

y.Sheets("DTR").Cells.Delete '<~~~No Error Here...?
y.Sheets("DTR").[a1].Paste   '<~~~Error Here
```

I thought it was strange that the deletion works fine, but paste does not.

It seems that I may be missing some fundamentals of the paste method - could someone please explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Other answers have provided ways to make it work, but don't explain what's going on.

```
y.Sheets("DTR")
```

That should really be `y.Worksheets("DTR")`, because the `Sheets` collection can contain non-worksheet items, such as charts for example.

Regardless, both the `Sheets` and the `Worksheets` collections' `Item` property (which is the *default property* of any collection type) yields an `Object`, which makes every chained member call that follows, a late-bound call.

And you don't get *IntelliSense* on late-bound calls, since these calls get resolved at run-time, by definition: you can call *anything* on an `Object`, and the code will happily compile:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Whatever
End Sub
```

Same as:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Whatever
End Sub
```

At run-time, if VBA can't find the `Whatever` member on the retrieved object's interface, it raises run-time error 438, "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Late-binding is powerful and very useful, but it also incurs overhead that you don't necessarily *need*.

Instead of working off an `Object`, you can *cast* the returned object reference to a specific type when you know what that type is - in this case we *know* we're dealing with a `Worksheet` object:

```
Dim target As Worksheet
Set target = y.Worksheets("DTR")
```

Now that you have an *early-bound* `Worksheet` object reference, *IntelliSense* can guide you:

[image: IntelliSense dropdown listing members of a Worksheet object]

And if you try to call a bogus member (e.g. `target.Whatever`), you'll get a compile-time error instead of a run-time error.

[image: compile error: member or data member not found]

When you do this:

```
target.[A1].Paste
```

You're using late-binding again, to retrieve the `A1` range. Instead, call the `Worksheet.Range` property getter to retrieve an early-bound `Range` object - and from there you'll see that when you type `.paste` there is no such thing as a `Paste` method in a `Range` object:

[image: autocompletion for Range.PasteSpecial]

And you get autocompletion and tooltips for everything as you type it:

[image: XLPasteType enum members listed for first parameter of Range.PasteSpecial method]

Answer (score 3):

You can `Copy` and `Paste` `Ranges` between sheets (and workbooks) using 1 line of code, just replace your code with the line below:

```
x.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy y.Sheets("DTR").[a1]
```

If you want to use the `PasteSpecial` method, you got to do it in 2 lines, but you need to add a parameter after the `PasteSpecial` , like `xlValues`, etc.

```
x.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
y.Sheets("DTR").[a1].PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Comment: Quick note, if you are just copying/pasting values, an alternative that avoids copy/paste is to just set he two ranges equal to each other: `Range([destination range]).value = Range([origin range]).value`

Comment: @BruceWayne ...with an asterisk: `Range` implicitly referring to the active workbook, for it to work when the *destination* workbook isn't the *source* workbook, the `Range` calls need to be fully-qualified with a `Worksheet` reference. Well at least the *destination* range in this case.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - yes, great call especially when he's copying from sheet to sheet, I forgot to mention that. Thanks for catching!  So, more specifically, it should be  `y.Sheets("DTR").[a1].Value = x.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value`.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `y.Sheets("DTR").[a1].PasteSpecial`

`Paste` does not work on ranges, to paste a range you have to use [PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx).  I believe by default it does everything but you can specify quite a bit, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @tjb1. Unfortunately, now I'm getting a run-time error: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your original code was two-fold.

1. The `Cells.Delete` statement appeared *after* the copy, but a delete action clears the clipboard.
2. The Paste method is a member of the Sheet object, not the Range object.

Adjusting your code, that becomes:

```
y.Sheets("DTR").Cells.Delete
x.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
y.Sheets("DTR").Paste y.Sheets("DTR").[a1]
```