# Compiling Data [Copy and Pasting] from List of Paths to One Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Quite new to VBA so bear with me for asking in much detail:

Objective:

1. Compile data from several files* (`Source`) , tab [Account]
2. Paste them in one sheet (`Target`). The header is at A4 so should start at A5. The catch is it is continuous so the data from SourceFile2 will be added only in the last row of Target File after data SourceFile1 has been added.
   *The code will be embedded in the `Target` where the file paths of the `Source` are also listed in one column

My code so far:

```
Sub Compile()
    Dim I as Long
    Dim WB_Target, WB_Source As Workbook
    Dim WS_Files, WS_Target as Worksheet
    Set WB_Target = ThisWorkbook
    Set WS_Files = WB_Target.Sheets("FilePaths") 'where the filepaths of sources are listed in column H
    Set WS_Target = WB_Target.Sheets("TargetSheet")
    
    For I = 1 to WS_Files.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
          If (Len(Dir(path.Range("H" & I))) > 0 then
                Set WB_Source = Workbooks.Open(WS_Files.Range("H") & i))
                Sheets("Account").Range("A1:M" & Sheets("Account").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
                Dim lastrow As Long
                    Set lastrow = Sheets("Full").Cells(Rows.Count, "A4").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                WS_Target.Range("A" & lastrow).Paste
                Application.CutCopyMode = false
                Workbooks("WB_Source").Close savechanges = False

          Else
             Next
          End If
     Next
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

My problem is there is error in the line "Set lastrow = ...." saying "Object required"

Appreciate any help. Thank you!!

Comment: Remove the `Set`

Comment: Hi BigBen, it now says "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: `"A4"` ---> `"A"`.

Comment: Thanks BigBen, sorry but another problem encountered in the line following that, i.e. "WS_Target.Range("A"& lastrow).Paste" 

it says "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640000/range-paste-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method